# Can I use a sports car in my TV commercial

Tags: copyright-transfer

Can I use a sports car in my TV commercial without asking the manufacrturers permission if I cover up the brand logo ?

Answer (score 1):

In short: [utility objects are not protected by copyright in the USA](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Copyright_rules_by_subject_matter#Utility_objects) and most countries, while sculptures are. A car is just an utility object although there are exceptions, like Batman's car, which is a work of art and therefore protected by copyright.